# SQL Server group by/ order by

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query

```
select
    datepart(yy, orderDate) as 'year',
    datename(mm, OrderDate) as 'month',
    count(*) as 'Orders'
from orders     (yeah I know its missing the schema, its from a book)
group by
    datepart(yy, orderdate),
    datename(mm, orderdate)
order by
    datepart(yy, orderdate),
    datename(mm, orderdate);
```

which returns 3 columns but `datename(mm, orderdate)` returns a string and therefore ordering by it puts August before January etc.

The solution to this was the following:

```
select
    datepart(yy, orderDate) as 'year',
    datename(mm, OrderDate) as 'month',
    count(*) as 'Orders'
from orders  (yeah i know its missing the schema, its from a book)
group by
    datepart(yy, orderdate),
    datename(mm, orderdate),
    datepart(mm, orderdate)
order by
    datepart(yy, orderdate),
    datepart(mm, orderdate);
```

I'm still a little confused with the whole group by / order by sections and how it actually works.

As far as I have understood, group by is creating a work table with 4 columns (that might be wrong) `datepart(yy, orderdate), datename(mm, orderdate), datepart(mm, orderdate)`, and a `count` column.

Each time it encounters an `orderdate` that it has in the work table it increases the count, 
otherwise it adds a new row?

Originally I thought I could remove the `DateName(mm, orderdate)` from within the group by section but the book said that's not possible.

If someone could step through what actually happens behind the scenes/point out a resource which explains how this works in a little more detail id appreciate it.

thanks for your help.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Are you just looking for an explanation of how your query is working?

Comment: Im just confused as to how this works and originally i thought i could remove the DateName from the Group By section.

Comment: `order by orderdate` doesn't work?  Or using `datepart` rather than `datename` in the `order` clause?

Comment: Show an example of the desired result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any time you use an aggregate function (COUNT,SUM,MAX, etc.) you need to include all other columns in a GROUP BY clause.  COUNT in your example is returning the number of records that have the same value for `datepart(yy, orderdate)`, `datename(mm, orderdate)`, `datepart(mm, orderdate)`.

An example:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, MAX(col4)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
```

Say this returned:

```
1,2,3,9
1,2,5,9
```

If you changed your query to this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, MIN(col3), MAX(col4)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

It would return:

```
1,2,3,9
```

Notice that I added an Aggregate function to `col3` (MIN) so I was able to remove `col3` from my GROUP BY clause.

Comment: It really doesn't matter how many columns the table has, it matters how many you are selecting and how many of those selected columns have an aggregate function applied to them.

Comment: One last question, if i removed the count(*) from the select statement, i would just get 2 columns returned, and they would be ordered as they were before right? (Im assuming i should use Distinct() instead).

Comment: Did you actually mean the second query would return `1,2,3,18`?

Comment: Nope.  I'm doing MAX on the final column, not a SUM.

Comment: `Anytime` `all other column must be included in group by` is not really true. All  relevent column must be either in aggr. function or group by, irrelevant are simply ignored. It not uncommon when the source table has far more  info columns than the query would ever concern, nobody aggregate on all irrelevent columns presented on source table.